# Enabling "Open Declaration" in Aptana Studio 3 PHP Editor

Tags: php, aptana

I used PDT for a bit in Eclipse, but wasn't satisfied with its Javascript formatting (especially with jQuery syntax), so I switched to Aptana Studio 3 (standalone version).

I'm really enjoying Aptana's features, but quite a few of things I enjoyed before are missing. For instance, I would like to be able to right-click on a function and use the `Open Declaration` feature to make AS3 go to the declaration of the function (whether it is in the current file or another).  The option is present in AS3, but when I try to use it nothing happens.

Any way I could enable this functionality in AS3?

Comment: I fixed this issue by changing the "nature" of the project I had imported.  I had to enable and them make primary the PHP "nature".  It was org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature.  I am discussing this issue on the Issue Tracker for Aptana Studio: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3331?focusedCommentId=163261

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PHP support in AS3 is in its full power when the 'Nature' of the project is recognized by the Studio (e.g. `com.aptana.editor.php.phpNature`).

As a future reference for others who stumble into this issue, the simplest way to set a `Nature` in the studio is by right-clicking the project, select 'Properties' and then select the `Project Natures` item. In that dialog, select the `PHP` item (the one with the icon next to it). You may also choose to make it as `primary`, but note that the only effect by doing so is visually (having a `P` icon on the project, marking it as a PHP project).

Also, by setting the nature this way, an Aptana PHP builder will be added to the `.project` file. This builder is needed for a proper indexing and code-assist for the project.

As a fix, we are considering some sort of notification that will allow you setting a nature when you import a project. That, in most cases, should solve it.

Hope that helps understanding how things work 'under the hood' :)